# Transfer e-mail messages between different Thunderbird profiles

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to transfer e-mail messages between [different Thunderbird profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-multiple-profiles) on the same machine? I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to create a new folder **Import** in the target profile, then a new subfolder called anything arbitrary (eg **Temp**), to establish the correct folder structure. After this exit Thunderbird and copy all the mail folders from the source profile into the same place where **Temp** resides (or create links if the folders are large, but this makes the source mails more vulnerable).

When TB is restarted, all the source profile's e-mails will be available as subfolders of **Import** and e-mails can be selected and copied at will into the target profile's normal folders (the vulnerability is that the e-mails could be moved by mistake, removing them from the source profile if they are links).

After all the required e-mails have been imported, the source profile copies or links can be removed, but **not from TB unless they are copies**. Finally remove **Temp** and **Import** from Thunderbird.

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time!